# How to fix declaration of AppWidgetProvider which is ignoring minwidth and minheight

Tags: android, appwidgetprovider

I have declared an AppWidgetProvider using

```
        <receiver android:name="uk.co.bmc.rad.widgets.NearestOpenCragWidgetProvider" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/nearest_open_crag_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

in res/xml I've added nearest_open_crag_Widget_info.xml containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    android:minWidth="486dp"
    android:minHeight="144dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/nearest_open_crag_widget"
    android:resizeMode="none">
</appwidget-provider>
```

I'm running this in the Eclipse emulator and no matter what sizes I specify for minWidth and minHeight the widget is added with the same dimensions.

As you can see at the bottom of the screen here: [image: screenshot]

---

In case it is a problem with the layout I'll include it here. There're three RelativeLayouts which I'm (hoping to be) hiding or revealing depending on state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:background="#525252" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/bmc_red"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/widget_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|fill_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/the_nearest_open_crag_is_"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/nearest_crag_loading_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nearest_crag_loading_error_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nearest_crag_error_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/error_image_content_description"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nearest_crag_loading_error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nearest_crag_error_image"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/ah_no_error_message_crikey_" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/nearest_open_crag_details_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/crag_list_spacer"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/list_view_name_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/crag_list_spacer"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/crag_list_spacer"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/list_view_distance_string"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/distance_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/crag_list_spacer"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/crag_list_spacer"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/crag_description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nearest_crag_btn_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/open_details" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Not probably a solution for your problem, but why are you using 3 RelativeLayouts? Only one might be better

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't ignore your settings

read here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

> If there is any inherent content padding in your widget background nine-patch, you should add to minWidth and minHeight accordingly.

Comment: There is no background nine-patch on my layout and no matter what minWidth and minHeight I specify the widget appears as in the screenshot. So minWidth and minHeight are being ignored or something else is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply same minHeight or minWidth to children element (looks retarded, isn't it?)

The settings in appwidget-provider works if you adjust same settings to children, in my your case it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:background="#525252" 
    android:minWidth="486dp"
    android:minHeight="144dp">
```